# Clear Read-Only Status при редактировании файла

Tags: webstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке сохранить отредактированный файл получаю такое диалоговое окно. Файл сохранить не получается, что делать?

Comment: А при чём тут ангуляр? Это проблема доступа к файлу. Выполните в терминале `sudo chown -R 'whoami' <folderName>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет доступа для сохранения этого файла, нужно изменить владельца всей папки с проектом. Выполните в терминале:

```
sudo chown -R 'whoami' <folderName>
```